# "MySQL server went away" after using mail()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that gets called frequently that runs a short database query and sends an email. The database code uses procedural-style mysql functions such as `mysql_query()`, etc. The email is sent using the `mail()` function.

99% of the time it ran without problem. However, sometimes I would get a "MySQL server has gone away" error. The original order of execution was to first send the mail with `mail()`, and then run the short update query. I switched the order of execution to run the query first and call `mail()` last, and now I never have a problem.

**The problem:** `mail()` somehow interferes with the database connection occasionally. Anybody have any ideas why? How should go about looking for the problem?

More info:

Once the mail script gives the "server went away" error, the query will always fail with that error if I try to run the script again. However, if I run the exact same query in phpMyAdmin it executes with no problem, and afterwards the mail script will work again.

Also, the script ran for many months without any problems - the "server went away" error just started recently, with no changes to any code or configuration on our part. Additionally, the script ran without problems during an extended period of time where the website was getting more than double the amount of traffic it currently gets, so it was not having any problems during a time when the server was dealing with many more database connections, etc., than it is right now.

PHP version: 5.3.3

MySQL version: 5.0.77-log Source distribution

Database is on a different server than the webserver/php script (not connecting to localhost)

Both the webserver and db server are Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

Comment: It would take some effort to post the relevant code in a readable state - I was hoping the situation would ring some bells without having to go through that. It seems to me that a configuration/environment issue is more likely than a php code issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a too short wait-time setting,
[official documentation has covered all the scenario](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

**PS** AFAIK, there is no `mysql server has went away`,
but `mysql server has gone away`

Comment: You are correct about "gone away" - sorry for the typo. 

The wait_timeout and interactive_timeout are set to 100. The "gone away" error is given after 100 seconds, so I guess the question is why is it suddenly taking 100 seconds to do a simple 'update `foo` = 1 where id = 2'